# Can degenerating Nicomachus' triangle down to $0$ area by using `Graph` be done?

Tags: graphs-and-networks, experimental-mathematics

I noticed a pattern in Nicomachus' Triangle that might be used to reduce the triangle to the number line. If the `Edge` size could be set to the absolute difference of its two vertices, I conjecture that this would occur **without** duplicates. **Edit 4---this produces deranged triangles whose areas are $0$.**

How can we set this `Edge` size?

**Edit 3**
Thanks to the link in the comment by: Rahul Narain, we have a viable solution:

> ```
> a = {k[{1, 1, 1}] <-> k[{1, 2, 1}],
>  k[{1, 2, 1}] <-> k[{1, 2, 2}],
>  k[{1, 2, 2}] <-> k[{1, 3,1}], k[{1, 3, 1}] <->
>  k[{1, 3, 2}], k[{1, 3, 2}] <-> k[{1, 3, 3}]}
> elength = {1, 1, 1, 2, 3}; (* kludge *)    
> Graph[a,VertexLabels -> "Name", EdgeWeight -> elength,
>  EdgeLabels\[Rule]"EdgeWeight", GraphLayout ->
>  {"VertexLayout" -> {"SpringElectricalEmbedding",
>  "EdgeWeighted" ->  True}}]
> ```

**Edit 2** The triangle inequality states that: if the sum of the lengths of the two shortest sides > length of the third side, we have a triangle. I want to change that to >=, then we have a triangle, straight line, or a point. All three types remain connected. If the sum < third side, we have an unconnected graph, thus an error under my definitions.

All of the examples I have found keep the original graph and manipulate the co-ordinates to get these edges. I want to use the normal graph transpositions, instead.

Motivation: I hope to show that we can take each triangle of an infinite prism and telescope it into a connected straight line. Then I hope to take that infinite array of straight lines and telescope it into a connected point. And I hope that point is 1.

To create the transposition from triangle to line:
Make original triangle graph;
Extract `Edge` and `Vertex` lists;
Create a new `Vertex` list using `k[{t,r,i}]`;
Create an `EdgeWeight` list using the absolute differences between the new vertices;
**The hard part!** Make a new graph using the weights as the actual lengths of the edges.
**An additional thought:** This might be as simple as changing the internal triangle inequality rule to allow straight lines.

**Edit**  When a 4-row triangle is graphed, we get a triangle with uniform edges. If we make the edges equal to the differences, the triangle loses its shape and becomes a straight line:
[image: line graph]
Above, set the edges to the differences to get the straight line.

```
(* This converts the generic triangle vertices to the specific Nicomachus' triangle vertices *)  
k[j_List] := 
Block[{t = j[[1]], r = j[[2]], i = j[[3]]}, (2 t - 1) 2^(-i + r)
3^(-1 + i)]  
(* These graph the generic and specific triangles *)
Graph[{{1, 1, 1} <-> {1, 2, 1}, {1, 2, 1} <-> {1, 2, 2}, {1, 2, 
2} <-> {1, 1, 1},
{1, 2, 1} <-> {1, 3, 1}, {1, 2, 1} <-> {1, 3, 2}, {1, 2, 2} <-> {1, 
  3, 2},
{1, 2, 2} <-> {1, 3, 3}, {1, 3, 1} <-> {1, 3, 2}, {1, 3, 2} <-> {1, 
3, 3}
}, VertexLabels -> "Name"]
Graph[{k[{1, 1, 1}] <-> k[{1, 2, 1}], k[{1, 2, 1}] <-> k[{1, 2, 2}], 
k[{1, 2, 2}] <-> k[{1, 1, 1}],
k[{1, 2, 1}] <-> k[{1, 3, 1}], k[{1, 2, 1}] <-> k[{1, 3, 2}], 
k[{1, 2, 2}] <-> k[{1, 3, 2}],
k[{1, 2, 2}] <-> k[{1, 3, 3}], k[{1, 3, 1}] <-> k[{1, 3, 2}], 
k[{1, 3, 2}] <-> k[{1, 3, 3}]
}, VertexLabels -> "Name" ]
(* These show the target graphs that I want when the `Edge` is set to the vertices differences *)
Graph[{{1, 1, 1} <-> {1, 2, 1}, {1, 2, 1} <-> {1, 2, 2},
{1, 2, 2} <-> {1, 3, 1}, {1, 3, 1} <-> {1, 3, 2},
{1, 3, 2} <-> {1, 3, 3}}, VertexLabels -> "Name"]
Graph[{k[{1, 1, 1}] <-> k[{1, 2, 1}], k[{1, 2, 1}] <-> k[{1, 2, 2}],
k[{1, 2, 2}] <-> k[{1, 3, 1}], k[{1, 3, 1}] <-> k[{1, 3, 2}],
k[{1, 3, 2}] <-> k[{1, 3, 3}]}, VertexLabels -> "Name"]
Graph[{k[{3, 1, 1}] <-> k[{3, 2, 1}], 
k[{3, 2, 1}] <-> k[{3, 2, 2}],
k[{3, 2, 2}] <-> k[{3, 3, 1}], k[{3, 3, 1}] <-> k[{3, 3, 2}],
k[{3, 3, 2}] <-> k[{3, 3, 3}]}, VertexLabels -> "Name"]
```

Comment: _"reduce the triangle to the number line"_ isn't clear enough for me. Could you explain further, please?

Comment: @belisarius, When triangle 1-2-3 is graphed we get a triangle with uniform edges. If we make the edges equal to the differences, the triangle loses its shape and becomes a straight line 1-2-3 with an edge back from 3-1.

Comment: Well, I still don't understand, but don't worry. Perhaps this one isn't my better day :)

Comment: @belisarius, I have posted the image. It's close to what we should get.

Comment: The question is hard to understand, but since you ask "How can we set this `Edge` size?" perhaps you want to [draw a graph with specified edge lengths](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18190/484)?

Comment: @RahulNarain, That looks like a viable approach. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`k[]` is function defined by you and `tri` is making `UndirectedEdge`-s

```
k[j_List] := Block[{t = j[[1]], r = j[[2]], i = j[[3]]},(2 t - 1) 2^(-i + r) 3^(-1 + i)]
tri[{t_, r_, i_}] := {{t, r, i} <-> {t, r + 1, i},
    {t, r + 1, i} <-> {t, r + 1, i + 1},{t, r + 1, i + 1} <-> {t, r, i}}
```

I remaked your code like this for making `Graph`.

```
d = 4;
data = Flatten@Table[tri[{1, i, j}],{i, 1, d - 1}, {j, 1, i}];
data2 = Apply[k[{##}] &, data, {2}];
vert = (VertexList@Graph@data)[[All, 2 ;; 3]];
co = Composition[
    RotationTransform[-\[Pi]/3],
    ShearingTransform[\[Pi]/6, {-1, 0}, {0, 1}], 
    ScalingTransform[Sqrt[3]/2, {0, 1}]] /@ vert;
Graph[data2,VertexLabels -> "Name",VertexCoordinates -> co]
```

> [image]

and I make number lines by following code, this is my guess you wanted.

```
l1 = k /@ VertexList@Graph@data;
l2 = Transpose@{l1, co};
l3 = Sort[l2, #1[[2, 1]] > #2[[2, 1]] && #1[[2, 2]] > #2[[2, 2]] &];
Reverse@(Transpose@l3)[[1]]
```

> `{1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 9, 12, 18, 27}`

```
PathGraph[Reverse@(Transpose@l3)[[1]], VertexLabels -> "Name"]
```

> [image: Blockquote]

**9-row triangle**

> [image]