# Generating social network graph from a CSV file

Tags: graphics, graphs-and-networks

I am new to Mathematica and wanted to generate undirected graph for data sets that show the relationships of organizations with each other. The data is in a square matrix. The cells of the matrix provide information about the relationships between each pair of organization (0 if no relationship exists; 1 if there is some relationship; 2 if the organizations work as partners; 3 if any of the board members serve in the paired organization). There are 81 organizations in the study, so the matrix is 81x81. The data data structure in CSV looks like the following.

[image: example of data structure]

I would very much appreciate if anyone would provide me the steps for generating the social network graph for the stated scenario using Mathematica 9.

Thanks!

-Brian

Comment: Possible starting point [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/WeightedAdjacencyGraph.html), but you actually ought to provide the code you are working on or at least the information you gathered through your research.

Comment: Use `AdjacencyGraph` to convert an adjacency matrix to a `Graph` object.  If you have trouble with some other step, such as reading the data into Mathematica, please make the question specific to that step.

Comment: As posed this question is not very attractive to those who could probably answer it. It asks them to do too much work for you -- work that you should have done before you posted the question. Your post would be much more attractive if you were to edit it to include: 1) a markdown formated data set that can copied into _Mathematica_ for use as test data; 2) an image showing what you expect the final output to look like; 3) the code you have tried and and explanation of why you find it unsatisfactory.

Comment: Also please refer to [this post](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/4520/17).

Answer (score 5):

Here is a start point. First, let's import your data

```
SetDirectory@NotebookDirectory[]
data=Import["data.csv"]
```

Now `data` should be something like this:

```
{{ ,ABC,DIA,ACE,SJ,KARMA,NOVICE},{ABC,0,2,3,1,2,1},{DIA,1,0,3,1,2,1},{ACE,2,1,0,3,1,2},{SJ,2,3,1,0,1,3},{KARMA,1,2,3,2,0,1},{NOVICE,1,1,2,3,2,0}}
```

Now you can use `WeightedAdjacencyGraph` as:

```
g=WeightedAdjacencyGraph[data[[2;;,2;;]]/.(0-> ∞),VertexLabels->MapIndexed[#2[[1]]-> #1&,data[[1,2;;]]]]
```

to get:

[image: Example Graph]

### Update

Here a function to color it (as suggested by @ubpdqn), and some additional formatting.

```
color[w_]:=Switch[w,1,Directive[Thick,Red],2,Directive[Thick,Darker@Green],3,Directive[Thick,Blue]];
edgeFormat=(#-> color@PropertyValue[{g, #}, EdgeWeight])&/@EdgeList[g];

g=WeightedAdjacencyGraph[data[[2;;,2;;]]/.(0-> ∞)
        ,VertexLabels->MapIndexed[#2[[1]]-> Placed[#1,Center]&,data[[1,2;;]]]
        ,VertexSize->0.27
        ,VertexStyle->White
        ,ImagePadding -> 20
        ,EdgeStyle->edgeFormat
]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you wanted to color code the relationships (using Murta's g):

Defining edge styles by weight:

```
es = Join @@ 
   MapThread[
    Thread[#1 -> #2] &, {(#[[All, 1]] & /@ 
       SortBy[GatherBy[{#, PropertyValue[{g, #}, EdgeWeight]} & /@ 
          EdgeList[g], #[[2]] &], #[[2]] &]), {Directive[Red, Thick], 
      Directive[Green, Thick], Directive[Blue, Thick]}}];
```

Here 1->Red,2->Green, 3->Blue. Visualizing:

```
WeightedAdjacencyGraph[data[[2 ;;, 2 ;;]] /. (0 -> \[Infinity]), 
 VertexLabels -> MapIndexed[#2[[1]] -> #1 &, data[[1, 2 ;;]]], 
 EdgeStyle -> es, ImagePadding -> 20]
```

[image]

Comment: The suggestions are extremely helpful for me - much appreciated.