# Find clusters of positive correlations

Tags: graphs-and-networks, cluster-analysis

I have a square matrix that shows relationships between 71 plants: 1 is a positive, -1 is negative, 0 is inconclusive and blanks are unknown:

I would like find the largest groups of plants that only have a positive relationship with no negative relationships among any of the members.

```
data = {{"", "Basil", "Cucumber", "Tomato", "Potato", "Peanut"}, {"Basil", 
  "", 0, -1, 0, ""}, {"Cucumber", "", "", "", -1, -1}, {"Tomato", -1,
   "", "", "", ""}, {"Potato", "", -1, 0, "", ""}, {"Peanut", 1, -1, 
  "", "", ""}}
```

The full set:

https://pastebin.com/06krccza

I was able to find out who to make a Weighted Adjacency Graph using:

[Generating social network graph from a CSV file](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/41147/generating-social-network-graph-from-a-csv-file)

However, I am looking for something that simplifies relationships to where I can pick out groups of good matches.

Comment: Why you do not have "Beans, French" in the columns of dataset but have it in rows? Also, are not relationships mutual, so you have to have symmetric values?

Comment: Please expand on "I want find clusters of plants that go well together." and clarify what you mean.

Comment: I corrected the mistakes in the data and made a simpler set.

Comment: I edited the question. I am looking for clusters of plants that only have positive relationships among the members of the group. A bonus would be candidates that may have a positive relationship based on a '0' value.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because any solution to the OP's question requires advice about clustering and handling missing values.  Advice from a statistician or from https://stats.stackexchange.com/ is needed first prior to implementation in *Mathematica*.

Comment: That seems sensible. I will ask on stats.stackexchange.com

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/clustering-variables-based-on-correlations-between-them.

Comment: There are no `1`s in your pastebin dataset. I only see `-1`s.

Comment: @Szabolcs I've fixed it. I think that Cliques are the closest to what I am looking for.

Comment: Or rather independent vertex sets: you want the largest set of vertices with no `-1`-relationship. You can form the graph of `-1`s and look for the largest independent vertex sets. This won't guarantee that there will be `1`-relationships, only that there will be no `-1`-relationship. Independent vetex sets are cliques in the complement graph, so yes, there is a relationship to cliques.

Comment: Your updated matrix is not symmetric. It is *almost*, but not quite symmetric.

Comment: You may also be interested in `IGCommunitiesSpinGlass` from the IGraph/M package. It is a community detection method that supports both positive and negative edge weights. You can find groups so that most connections within the groups are positive, and negative connections tend to be inbetween different groups.

Answer (score 5):

Ingest the data, make a matrix of the correlations, make a list with plant names:

```
data = Get["~/Downloads/06krccza.txt"];
matData = data[[2 ;; -1, 2 ;; -1]];
lsPlantNames = Rest@data[[1]];
Length[lsPlantNames]

(*70*)
```

Make association of correlations and distances:

```
aCors = Association@
   Map[lsPlantNames[[#[[1]]]] -> #[[2]] &, 
    Most[ArrayRules[SparseArray[matData]]]];
aDists = Map[
   N@Which[TrueQ[# == 1], 0, TrueQ[# == -1], 1000, True, 1] &, aCors];
```

Note that in order to address question's main, non-trivial condition

> [...] find the largest groups of plants that only have a positive relationship with no negative relationships among any of the members.

the distances in `aDists` that correspond to negative correlations are (very) large numbers.

Make a nearest neighbors graph:

```
gr = NearestNeighborGraph[lsPlantNames, {90, 0.1}, 
  DistanceFunction -> (Lookup[aDists, Key[{#1, #2}], 1000] &), 
  Method -> "Octree", DirectedEdges -> False, 
  GraphLayout -> "SpringElectricalEmbedding", VertexLabels -> "Name"]
```

[image]

Find cliques / clusters:

```
lsClqs = FindClique[gr, Infinity, All];
Length[lsClqs]
```

Examine the clusters lengths:

```
Tally[Length /@ lsClqs]

(*{{4, 1}, {3, 10}, {2, 32}, {1, 36}}*)
```

Verify the found clusters do not have negative correlations

```
aHasNegativeCor = 
  Association[# -> FreeQ[Outer[aCors[{##}] &, #, #], -1] & /@ clqs];
Tally[Values[aHasNegativeCor]]

(*{{True, 78}, {False, 1}}*)
```

Examine the negative correlation and/or delete it:

```
Select[aHasNegativeCor, ! # &]

(*<|{"Beans, Runner", "Garlic", "Leek"} -> False|>*)
```

Final result:

```
lsClqs2 = Keys[Select[aHasNegativeCor, # &]];
lsClqs2[[1 ;; 4]]

(*{{"Onion", "Pea", "Potato", "Tomato"}, {"Onion", "Parsnip", 
  "Tomato"}, {"Leek", "Onion", "Pea"}, {"Garlic", "Leek", "Pea"}}*)
```

### First answer

Some code that might help these questions.

Since data was not provided, let us make some:

```
SeedRandom[32]; 
data2 = Block[{lsWords = Sort@RandomWord[71], res},
   res = Flatten[
     Table[{lsWords[[i]], lsWords[[j]], 
       RandomChoice[{0.1, 0.8, 0.1} -> {-1, 0, 1}]}, {i, 1, 
       Length[lsWords]}, {j, i + 1, Length[lsWords]}], 1];
   res = Union[Join[res, res[[All, {2, 1, 3}]]]];
   Select[res, #[[3]] != 0 &]
   ];
```

Make a graph with the positive correlations only:

```
 gr = Graph[UndirectedEdge @@@ Select[data2, #[[3]] > 0 &]]
```

Find graph communities:

```
 CommunityGraphPlot[gr, VertexLabels -> "Name"]
```

[image]

If you provide the actual data more adequate answers might be given.

Comment: Having executed the first part of your code, I obtained "RandomWord::nodict: Word list is not available for language Ukrainian.". A good code is a commented code.

Comment: @user64494 **1)** *Having executed the first part of your code, I obtained "RandomWord::nodict: Word list is not available for language Ukrainian."* -- this should not be happening in my opinion; consider filing a bug report. And/or run your Mathematica copy with a different language localization. **2)** *A good code is a commented code* -- Agreed. What this has to do with my post?

Comment: Thank you Anton. That what I was looking for. I have updated the question to link the data.

Comment: Anton, my Mathematica runs in English. Your comments to your code are too poor or absent at all..

Comment: @user64494 "Your comments to your code are too poor or absent at all." -- I disagree. And if you have in mind the code for the data generation, then I would say that the data generation is not important -- note, that OP did provide actual data after I posted my answer. Also, you cannot figure out `RandomWord` peculiarities by reading its function page.

Comment: @fitzsnaggle The data matrix you provided in pastebin does not have values that are 1.

Comment: @AntonAntonov I've fixed it and edited the question. It was a search and replace mistake.

Comment: @AntonAntonov I was able to make a graph using your solution above. I think FindCliques is what I was looking for.

Comment: @fitzsnaggle Yes, `NearestNeighborsGraph` and `FindClique` seem to work on your data, but one has to check that the obtained cliques/clusters do not have negative correlations. (See my answer update.)

Comment: Anton, sorry, I have nothing to discuss with you in such unconstructive  manner.

Comment: @user64494 "I have nothing to discuss with you in such unconstructive manner." -- No, all of my responses to your comments were constructive: detailed and concrete enough.