# Styling the edges of a graph according to the multiplicities of the edges

Tags: plotting, graphics, graphs-and-networks

I used the following code to make a simple triangle, in which the nodes have different effects each other:

```
data = {{0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 2}, {3, 0, 0}};
AdjacencyGraph[data, VertexLabels -> "Name"]
```

[image: graph]

That gave me three edges between nodes 1 and 3, and two edges between nodes 2 and 3. How can I show these multiplicities with edges that range from thin to thick.

---

@prgrad and @m_goldberg

I want to transform my graph into one which gives me single edge between the nodes. See the following picture:

for each different edge value of a different style. For example, for +3 dark black, for -3 dark red, etc.

[image]

Can you help to make a graph from my adjacency matrix that has these (minus and plus) labels?

Comment: Are you asking how to transform your graph into one that has a single edge between each connected vertex, but indicates the multiplicity of the corresponding edge in your graph by increased thickness?

Comment: There are some answers [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4520/how-to-get-graph-layout-that-reflects-edge-weights) which will also answer your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taking into account the new information from your edit, I propose the following:

Function to produce the edge labels according to multiplicity indicated in the adjacency matrix.

```
 edgeLbl[multipliciy_] := 
   Style[StringJoin @ ConstantArray["+", multipliciy], Background -> White]
```

Function to style the edges according to multiplicity.

```
 edgeStyle[multipliciy_] := AbsoluteThickness[multipliciy]
```

My reason for defining these functions is to make it easy to modify the look of graph edges without having to modify the main graph making function, which is:

```
gr[adjMatrix_] :=
  Module[{m, edges, style, lbls},
   m = Map[Boole[# > 0] &, adjMatrix, {2}];
   edges = EdgeList @ AdjacencyGraph[m];
   style = Rule[#, edgeStyle[adjMatrix[[#[[1]], #[[2]]]]]] & /@ edges;
   lbls = Rule[#, edgeLbl[adjMatrix[[#[[1]], #[[2]]]]]] & /@ edges;
   AdjacencyGraph[m,
     EdgeStyle -> style,
     EdgeLabels -> lbls,
     VertexLabels -> "Name"]]

gr[{{0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 2}, {3, 0, 0}}]
```

[image: graph]

#### Update

The above doesn't adjust the size of the arrow heads according to the multiplicity. If you think that should happen, then a another function is needed.

```
arrow[multipliciy_] := 
  GraphElementData[{"FilledArrow", "ArrowSize" -> .018 + .01 multipliciy}]

gr[adjMatrix_] :=
  Module[{m, edges, style, arrows, lbls},
    m = Map[Boole[# > 0] &, adjMatrix, {2}];
    edges = EdgeList@AdjacencyGraph[m];
    style = Rule[#, edgeStyle[adjMatrix[[#[[1]], #[[2]]]]]] & /@ edges;
    lbls = Rule[#, edgeLbl[adjMatrix[[#[[1]], #[[2]]]]]] & /@ edges;
    arrows = Rule[#, arrow[adjMatrix[[#[[1]], #[[2]]]]]] & /@ edges;
    AdjacencyGraph[m,
      EdgeStyle -> style,
      EdgeLabels -> lbls,
      EdgeShapeFunction -> arrows,
      VertexLabels -> "Name"]]

gr[{{0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 2}, {3, 0, 0}}]
```

[image: graph-2]

Answer (score 4):

If I understand your question correctly, you want the thickness of the edge to depend on the vertex the edge is directed towards?

If so, then you will need to use `EdgeShapeFunction`:

```
data = {{0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 2}, {3, 0, 0}};
AdjacencyGraph[data, VertexLabels -> "Name",
EdgeShapeFunction ->
({
 Thickness[Last[#2]*0.01],
 Arrowheads[Sqrt[Last[#2]*0.01]],
 Arrow[#1]} &
)]
```

[image: thickness of plotting edge graph]]

`EdgeShapeFunction` provides two parameters:

1. The coordinates of the vertices in the first argument `#1`, which is used to give the points between which the arrow should be drawn.
2. The name of the vertices between which the arrow is directed in the second argument `#2`. In this code I take the second value of `#2` using `Last[#2]`, that is the name of the vertex the arrow is going towards.

It is the second argument that allows us to define the thickness of the edge using `Thickness`. I multiply the vertex number by 0.01 to scale down the thickness to an appropriate size. I also have to define the size of the 'Arrowheads', and I find that taking the square of the values used for `Thickness` works well.

If you wanted to define the thickness according to the value of the vertex the edges are coming from you would use `First[#2]` rather than `Last[#2]`.

Note also that the brackets `()` enclosing the `EdgeShapeFunction` list are important to making the code work. If I remember correctly this is because we are using `DirectedEdges`: see 'Possible Issues' in: http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EdgeShapeFunction.html#

P