# Networkgraph, Thickness of edges based on calculated values

Tags: graphs-and-networks

On this blogsite I've read a interesting [blog about visualising a correlation matrix](http://blog.wolfram.com/2012/06/01/graph-theory-and-finance-in-mathematica/).

So I started with a simple file like:

```
data = {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1}, {2, 2, 14, 16, 2, 3, 4, 5, 
   1}, {1, 1, 12, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 2}, {1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}, {1, 
   6, 5, 1, 4, 3, 1, 2, 1}, {1, 2, 3, 6, 8, 10, 13, 15, 17}, {2, 6, 
   10, 12, 15, 21, 30, 35, 40}, {2, 6, 10, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3}, {2, 8, 
   12, 8, 14, 2, 3, 4, 5}};

datahead = { "var1", "var2", "var3", "var4", "var5", "var6", "var7", 
  "var8", "var9"};
```

Then I calculated a correlation-matrix

```
datacor = N[Correlation[data]];
```

In the same blog I read about this function

```
portfolioMaxtrix[θ_] := 
 ReplacePart[datacor, {i_, i_} -> 0] /. {x_ /; x > θ -> 1, 
   x_ /; x <= θ -> 0};
```

So I created a graph

```
AdjacencyGraph[portfolioMaxtrix[0.6], 
 VertexLabels -> 
  MapThread[
   Rule, {Range[Length[datahead]], 
    Style[#, 7, GrayLevel[.3], FontFamily -> "Verdana"] & /@ 
     datahead}], VertexSize -> Large, 
 GraphLayout -> {"PackingLayout" -> "ClosestPacking"}, 
 ImagePadding -> 20];
```

Then I calculated two dimensions.

```
numrows = Length[datacor];
numvar = Length[datacor[[1]]];
```

The idea is that I want to vary the thickness of the lines in the network graph, based on the correlation coeffcient.

```
edgestyle = 
 Table[x <-> y -> Thickness@Abs@datacor[[x, y]], {x, 1, numrows}, {y, 
   1, numvar}]
```

This gives the following result:

```
{{1 <-> 1 -> Thickness[1.], 1 <-> 2 -> Thickness[0.594442], 
  1 <-> 3 -> Thickness[0.737199], 1 <-> 4 -> Thickness[0.84042], 
  1 <-> 5 -> Thickness[0.558359], 1 <-> 6 -> Thickness[0.294155], 
  1 <-> 7 -> Thickness[0.337391], 1 <-> 8 -> Thickness[0.338754], 
  1 <-> 9 -> Thickness[0.28061]}, {2 <-> 1 -> Thickness[0.594442], 
  2 <-> 2 -> Thickness[1.], 2 <-> 3 -> Thickness[0.281924], 
  2 <-> 4 -> Thickness[0.215337], 2 <-> 5 -> Thickness[0.724505],.....}}
```

When I run the next code, it works fine:

```
AdjacencyGraph[portfolioMaxtrix[0.6], 
 VertexLabels -> 
  MapThread[
   Rule, {Range[Length[datahead]], 
    Style[#, 7, GrayLevel[.3], FontFamily -> "Verdana"] & /@ 
     datahead}], VertexSize -> Large, 
 GraphLayout -> {"PackingLayout" -> "ClosestPacking"}, 
 EdgeStyle -> {1 <-> 4 -> Thickness[0.05]}, ImagePadding -> 20]
```

Then I tried this one

```
AdjacencyGraph[portfolioMaxtrix[0.6], 
 VertexLabels -> 
  MapThread[
   Rule, {Range[Length[datahead]], 
    Style[#, 7, GrayLevel[.3], FontFamily -> "Verdana"] & /@ 
     datahead}], VertexSize -> Large, 
 GraphLayout -> {"PackingLayout" -> "ClosestPacking"}, 
 EdgeStyle -> edgestyle, ImagePadding -> 20]
```

This goes wrong. As far as I understand, because I selected more edges in `EdgeStyle` then used by the `portfolioMaxtrix`-function.

I tried several options like 'DeleteCases' but all failed. Does anyone have a suggestion how to solve this issue?

Comment: Does `edgestyle2 = {x_ <-> y_ :> Thickness[Abs@datacor[[x, y]]/20]}`  (in place of your `edgestyle`) give something close tto what you need?

Comment: Related question: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/89749/styling-the-edges-of-a-graph-according-to-the-multiplicities-of-the-edges

Comment: also related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6440/8

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
portfolioMaxtrix[p_] :=
 Sign @ Threshold[ReplacePart[datacor, {i_, i_} -> 0], p]

pmat = portfolioMaxtrix[0.6];
```

Get positions of chosen correlations (these correspond to the edges of the graph)

```
(pos = Position[1] @ UpperTriangularize @ pmat) // MatrixForm
```

[image]

Extract the correlation values and rescale

```
cor = Rescale @ Extract[datacor, pos]/100;
```

Build the `EdgeStyle` - rules

```
tra = Rule @@@ Transpose[{UndirectedEdge @@@ pos, Thickness /@ cor}];
```

Plot

```
AdjacencyGraph[pmat,
 VertexLabels -> 
  MapThread[Rule, 
   {Range[Length[datahead]], 
    Style[#, 13, GrayLevel[.3], FontFamily -> "Verdana"] & /@ datahead}],
 VertexSize -> Large,
 GraphLayout -> {"PackingLayout" -> "ClosestPacking"},
 EdgeStyle -> tra,
 ImagePadding -> 40]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Similar to @eldo

You can set your own limit of a strong correlation, however:

```
Chop[LowerTriangularize[Correlation[data] // N, -1], 0.6] /. 
  0 -> \[Infinity] // MatrixForm
```

[image]

```
WeightedAdjacencyGraph[%]
```

[image]

If you want to distinguish between positive and negative:

```
SetProperty[%, 
 EdgeStyle -> {x_ :> (PropertyValue[{%, x}, 
       EdgeWeight] /. {a_?Positive -> 
        Directive[Thickness[Abs@a/400000] , Opacity[.5], Green], 
       b_?Negative -> 
        Directive[Thickness[Abs@b/400000] , Opacity[.5], Red]})}]
```

[image]