# How can I make and visualize a connected lattice structure with weighted bonds?

Tags: graphs-and-networks, visualization, physics, lattices

For a problem in condensed matter I am computing nearest-neighbor correlations (real numbers) between spins on a lattice. A good way to visualize this is by drawing a lattice structure with bonds between sites whose color corresponds to the sign of the correlation and thickness corresponds to the strength (size) of the correlation. I was hoping I could get some advice on how to do this with Mathematica.

My problem in particular deals with ladder lattices which stitch together sections of 2-leg ladders with those of 3-leg ladders. Each lattice is parameterized by three integers: $N$, the number of 2-leg rungs per section, $M$, the number of 3-leg rungs per section, and $L$, the number of sections. I've drawn a picture of lattice with hypothetical correlation bonds for the parameters $N=4$, $M=3$, $L=1$ here: [image]

Hopefully it is clear what I am asking for; I know Mathematica has some pretty neat tools for graphs but I am not familiar with which ones would lend themselves to this problem most naturally. Thanks!

Comment: Have you seen this? [(6440)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6440/121)

Comment: Thanks @Mr.Wizard, I will look that over! But I am also interested in building the lattice structure itself, perhaps with some method of stitching together various `GridGraph` objects. It would be valuable to have some insight into an intelligent way of doing this.

Comment: Could you provide the full specification to produce the hand-drawn graph?  Do you have a table of weights?  Are these derived from other values?

Comment: For the scope of this problem, you can just think of the weights as a table of real numbers, each in the interval $[-1,1]$. The table comes from a complicated tensor network contraction computed by a C++ program, but all Mathematica should need to know are $(N,M,L)$ to build the Lattice and the table of weights to draw and color the lines between vertices.

Comment: Can you tell, why you want to use a `Graph` for this? If the structure is always built from simple repeating ladders like yours, why don't you write a visualization yourself? When I see this right, you only need points and bonds of different thickness. Everything else can be built upon these basic structures.

Comment: Also look at [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/89749/)

Comment: I demonstrated some easy visualization and a method of graph construction if you're sitting on correlation data in the form of a sparse-table.  If this isn't the form of data, maybe you can give an example of your correlation data, as in for your hand-drawn picture?

Answer (score 3):

I think this is a fine question, and graphs are a great way of representing lattices, so it's natural to want to visualize using them.

UPDATE: I originally read this as a visualization question.  I'll address construction at the bottom.

---

## Visualization

### Straight Render

Here's a toy ladder graph.

```
 someGraph=Graph[{node[16], node[15], node[14], node[4], node[12], node[13], node[11], node[3], node[9], node[6], node[10], node[2], node[8], node[7], 
  node[1], node[5]}, {UndirectedEdge[node[16], node[15]], UndirectedEdge[node[14], node[4]], UndirectedEdge[node[16], node[14]], 
  UndirectedEdge[node[12], node[13]], UndirectedEdge[node[11], node[12]], UndirectedEdge[node[3], node[11]], 
  UndirectedEdge[node[13], node[15]], UndirectedEdge[node[12], node[16]], UndirectedEdge[node[11], node[14]], 
  UndirectedEdge[node[3], node[4]], UndirectedEdge[node[15], node[9]], UndirectedEdge[node[6], node[13]], 
  UndirectedEdge[node[10], node[2]], UndirectedEdge[node[8], node[9]], UndirectedEdge[node[10], node[8]], UndirectedEdge[node[7], node[1]], 
  UndirectedEdge[node[5], node[7]], UndirectedEdge[node[6], node[5]], UndirectedEdge[node[1], node[2]], UndirectedEdge[node[7], node[10]], 
  UndirectedEdge[node[5], node[8]], UndirectedEdge[node[6], node[9]]}]
```

It looks like this:
 [image]

You care about correlations between adjacent (connected) nodes, I'll assume scaled between -1 and 1, and I'll generate some data so there'll be some strongly and weakly weighted edges:

```
(correlationWeight[#] = 
     RandomChoice[{-1, 1}]*(-RandomInteger[{0, 2}] 80/110 + 1);
    correlationWeight[# /. 
       UndirectedEdge[a_, b_] :> UndirectedEdge[b, a]] = 
     correlationWeight[#]) & /@ EdgeList[someGraph];
```

*Note I make sure correlationWeight is defined no matter which order someone hands me an UndirectedEdge.*

We'll need an edge rendering function to care about the thickness, and color:

```
efStraight[pts_List, 
  edge_] := {Thickness[Abs[correlationWeight[edge]]/40], 
  If[Sign[correlationWeight[edge]] > 0, Black, Blue], Line[pts]}
```

and

```
Graph[someGraph, 
 VertexShapeFunction -> ({EdgeForm[{Thickness[.04], Black}], 
     Disk[#, .02],
     EdgeForm[{Thickness[.015], White}], Disk[#, .02]} &),
 EdgeShapeFunction -> efStraight]
```

produces:

[image: straightRender]

Hopefully this gives you a good idea of the salient features.

---

### Streaky Render

For fun I thought I'd play around for a few seconds trying to reproduce your hand-drawn effect.

A natural first attempt is to just run it through Simon Wood's ever [popular](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/11355/51526):

```
xkcdDistort[p_] := 
  Module[{r, ix, iy}, 
   r = ImagePad[Rasterize@p, 10, Padding -> White];
   {ix, iy} = 
    Table[RandomImage[{-1, 1}, ImageDimensions@r]~ImageConvolve~
      GaussianMatrix[10], {2}];
   ImagePad[
    ImageTransformation[
     r, # + 15 {ImageValue[ix, #], ImageValue[iy, #]} &, 
     DataRange -> Full], -5]];
```

giving us:

[image: xkcdDistort]

That's great, but everything's all rasterized, and I was curious about reproducing  the streaks from the repeated marker strokes.  Here's a first attempt borrowing the BSpline wiggles from [Mr. Wizard](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/11402/51526) :

```
efStreaky[pts_List, e_] := {Thickness[Abs[correlationWeight[e]]/40], 
  If[Sign[correlationWeight[e]] > 0, Opacity[.4, Black], 
   Opacity[.5, RGBColor[0., 0.26, 0.79]]], 
  setBackLineJiggle[pts, xx = RandomReal[{1/8, 1/5}]], 
  setBackLineJiggle[pts, xx*1.1 ]}

Graph[someGraph, 
 VertexShapeFunction -> ({EdgeForm[{Thickness[.04], Black}], 
     Disk[#, .02],
     EdgeForm[{Thickness[.015], White}], Disk[#, .02]} &),
 EdgeShapeFunction -> efStreaky]
```

yielding

[image: streakyRender]

and

[image: streakyRender2]

with wiggle helper code:

```
split[{a_, b_}] := 
 If[a == b, {b}, 
  With[{n = Ceiling[3 Norm[a - b]]}, 
   Array[{n - #, #}/n &, n].{a, b}]];
partition[{x_, y__}] := Partition[{x, x, y}, 2, 1];
nudge[L : {a_, b_}, d_] := Mean@L + d Cross[a - b];
wiggle[pts : {{_, _} ..}, 
  d_: {-0.15, 0.15}] := ## &[#~nudge~RandomReal@d, #[[2]]] & /@ 
  partition[Join @@ split /@ partition@pts];
setBackLineJiggle[{a_, b_}, n_] := BSplineCurve@wiggle@{a + n (b - a) +
   RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 2] /(30 Norm[b - a]),  b - n (b - a)}
```

---

## Graph Construction

### From Correlation Data

Somehow you have to be starting with some correlation data between lattice sites.  One way you could be storing it is a sparse array that has values when sites have non-vanishing correlation between them.

Something like a sparse version of:

```
correlationTable = {{0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, -(3/11), 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
   0, 0}, {-1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -(3/11), 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0,
    0, 0, 5/11, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 5/11, 0, 
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3/11, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3/11, 1, 5/
   11, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 3/11, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
   0, -1, 0, 0, 0}, {-(3/11), 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
   0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 5/11, 0, 0, 0, -(3/11), 5/11, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
   0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, -(3/11), 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -(3/11), 
   0}, {0, -(3/11), 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 5/11, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0,
    0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -(5/11), 0, -(3/11), 0, 0}, {0, 0, 
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -(5/11), 0, 1, 0, 0, 3/11}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 
   0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 3/11, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 3/11, 0, 0, 0, 
   0, 0, 0, -(3/11), 0, 0, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -(3/11),
    0, 0, 0, 3/11, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3/11, 
   0, 1, 1, 0}};
```

i.e.

[image: correlationTable]

It's very easy to turn this data, or it's sparse version, into a graph, connecting only edges with non-vanishing correlation.

Here's one way, that builds the correlationWeight function used above in one go:

```
someGraph2 = (SparseArray[correlationTable] // 
       ArrayRules)[[1 ;; -2]] /. 
    Rule[{a_, b_}, 
      weight_] :> (correlationWeight[
        UndirectedEdge[node[a], node[b]]] = weight;
      correlationWeight[UndirectedEdge[node[b], node[a]]] = weight; 
      UndirectedEdge @@ Sort[{node[a], node[b]}]) // Union // Graph
```