# how make the thickness of the edges reflect the weights?

Tags: graphs-and-networks

How Can I represent with thickness of the edges the weights of this graph?

```
Graph[{1 <-> 2, 2 <-> 3, 3 <-> 1}, EdgeWeight -> {1, 3, 5}]
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/4547/121) a duplicate? Also at least related: [(6440)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6440/121)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you can't refer to a `PropertyValue` of the graph you are currently constructing, you could have an auxiliary graph that holds the properties, and another graph that draws based on those properties.

For example you could make the color and thickness depend on the weight via

```
g = Graph[{1 <-> 2, 2 <-> 3, 3 <-> 1}, EdgeWeight -> {2, 8, 14}];

shapeFunc = With[{weight = PropertyValue[{g, #2}, EdgeWeight]},
    {AbsoluteThickness[weight], Hue[weight/14.], Line@#1}] &;
Graph[g, EdgeStyle -> Blue, EdgeShapeFunction -> shapeFunc]
```

The arguments given to the `EdgeShapeFunction` are 1) the vertex coordinates for the endpoints of the line segment, and 2) the edge itself.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: so with your example color and thickness reflect in same time weights?

Comment: and with a network of 500 edges for example how can I have a good thick and good representation?

Answer (score 7):

EdgeStyle can plot the edges with different thicknesses

```
spec = {1 <-> 2, 2 <-> 3, 3 <-> 1};
thickness = {0.01, 0.02, 0.03};
Graph[spec, EdgeStyle -> Thread[spec -> (Thickness[#] & /@ thickness)]]
```

[image]

Here the thickness of the lines is 1/10 of the original edgeweights, otherwise they are very thick. You can also specify the color the same way:

```
spec = {1 <-> 2, 2 <-> 3, 3 <-> 1};
thickness = {0.01, 0.02, 0.03};
color = {0., 0.5, 0.6};
Graph[spec, EdgeStyle -> Thread[spec -> 
      Thread@{(Hue[#] & /@ color), (Thickness[#] & /@ thickness)}]]
```

[image]

Comment: Ok @bill s maybe can it be normalize thickness wiith max value of edgeweights?

Comment: Sure, you can set the values in any desired manner.

Answer (score 6):

With the [IGraph/M package](http://szhorvat.net/mathematica/IGraphM), it is very easy to do styling like this.  You will find several similar examples in the documentation under Utilities → Property Handling Functions.

```
IGEdgeMap[
 AbsoluteThickness[1.5 #] &,
 EdgeStyle -> IGEdgeProp[EdgeWeight],
 g
]
```

What does `IGEdgeMap` do?  It [`Map`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Map.html)s the function `AbsoluteThickness[1.5 #] &` over the list returned by `IGEdgeProp[EdgeWeight][g]`, and assigned the result to the `EdgeStyle` edge property of `g`.

`IGEdgeProp[EdgeWeight]` is a *property extractor*. It is a function that, when applied to the graph `g`, will return the list of `EdgeWeight`s. You can extract any other edge property this way.